# Most effective way to revert multiple commits in master branch

Tags: git

Current project has a change design that need to ditch the passed 5 consecutive commits till HEAD. But instead of make a single commit revert, I am thinking to have a new change to rebased to the `HEAD - 5`th commit so completely get rid of the past changes in GIT history.

I was able to do `git rebase 123456` where 123456 is the `HEAD - 5`th commit in the `feature` branch, however not sure how to push such change in `master` branch because the diff in PR didn't show the "revert" part.

Just wondering if any effective way to revert commits completely (even remove commit history) to an unmodifiable `master` branch.

Comment: You can do that, but you can’t get rid of history with a pull request. You would have to force push directly to master.

Comment: @Ry- , thanks but what if the master branch is disabled for modification?

Comment: Then you can’t do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverting the last 5 commits can be done with

```
git revert HEAD~5..HEAD
```

It will create a revert commit per each one of the 5 commits.

If you don't mind creating a single commit for all changes, it can be done with

```
git restore --staged --worktree --source=HEAD~5 -- .
git commit -m "going back 5 commits"
```

Comment: Thank you but that will still keep 5 (original) + 1 (revert) = 6 commits in the master branch? Is there a way to wipe those 5 commits in an unmodifiable `master` branch by PR merge?

Comment: That requires rewriting history. You can do a `git reset --hard HEAD~5`. But this bit from the question makes it sound like you _can´t_ rewrite history: "_unmodifiable_ `master` branch". So, assuming it means that you can't remove stuff from the branch, then the answer is **no**.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `git diff --name-only` to get the list of files that were changed in the commits.  Then using `git checkout <last good sha>` to get the files, after these checkouts I can do a commit that is a specific revert of the commit.

The problem with doing `git rebase` is that it changes history and depending on the branches that can make things complicated in dealing with other branches.  And in particular for using PR, I would prefer not rebasing master.  Once a commit got there, it is there.